# How to resolve the Composer dependencies conflicts (a clean way)?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm writing a PHP application based on Symfony `v5.0.11`. Now I want to upgrade Symfony to the `^v5.2`. (The Composer version is `2.0.12`.)

```
$ composer require symfony/framework-bundle:^5.2
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/framework-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.6] require symfony/cache ^5.2 -> found symfony/cache[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.6] but the package is fixed to v5.0.11 (lock file version) by a partia
l update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/framework-bundle ^5.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.6].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

It hasn't worked, because the `symfony/cache` package is locked to the `v5.0.11` version in `composer.lock`. But when I try using the `--with-all-dependencies` option, as suggested in the error message:

```
$ composer require --update-with-all-dependencies symfony/framework-bundle:^5.2
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/framework-bundle --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.6] require symfony/cache ^5.2 -> found symfony/cache[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another
 require.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/framework-bundle ^5.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Now the problem is, that Composer cannot install the needed version of the package `symfony/cache`, possibly "*because it conflicts with another require*".

How to solve these / such Composer issues cleanly? ("Clean" means here: without resetting the project, running the across-the-board `composer update`, or making other brutal stuff with unpredictable side-effects.)

---

**UPDATE**

- `composer.json`
- `composer.lock`
- `symfony.lock`

**`composer.json`**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3.0 || ^8.0.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.9",
        "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.15",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.0",
        "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^4.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/routing": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.30",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform": {}
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "5.0.*"
        }
    }
}
```

**`composer.lock`**

```
{
    ...
        {
            "name": "symfony/framework-bundle",
            "version": "v5.0.11",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle.git",
                "reference": "0fc0a93f8bbe465d0b483e21b087d432baa92c16"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/framework-bundle/zipball/0fc0a93f8bbe465d0b483e21b087d432baa92c16",
                "reference": "0fc0a93f8bbe465d0b483e21b087d432baa92c16",
                "shasum": ""
            },
            "require": {
                "ext-xml": "*",
                "php": ">=7.2.5",
                "symfony/cache": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/config": "^5.0",
                "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.0.1",
                "symfony/error-handler": "^4.4.1|^5.0.1",
                "symfony/filesystem": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/finder": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/http-foundation": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/http-kernel": "^5.0",
                "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
                "symfony/routing": "^5.0"
            },
            "conflict": {
                "doctrine/persistence": "<1.3",
                "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "<3.0",
                "phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "<0.2.1",
                "phpunit/phpunit": "<5.4.3",
                "symfony/asset": "<4.4",
                "symfony/browser-kit": "<4.4",
                "symfony/console": "<4.4",
                "symfony/dom-crawler": "<4.4",
                "symfony/dotenv": "<4.4",
                "symfony/form": "<4.4",
                "symfony/http-client": "<4.4",
                "symfony/lock": "<4.4",
                "symfony/mailer": "<4.4",
                "symfony/messenger": "<4.4",
                "symfony/mime": "<4.4",
                "symfony/property-info": "<4.4",
                "symfony/serializer": "<4.4",
                "symfony/stopwatch": "<4.4",
                "symfony/translation": "<5.0",
                "symfony/twig-bridge": "<4.4",
                "symfony/twig-bundle": "<4.4",
                "symfony/validator": "<4.4",
                "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "<4.4",
                "symfony/workflow": "<4.4"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "doctrine/annotations": "~1.7",
                "doctrine/cache": "~1.0",
                "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.8",
                "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^3.0|^4.0",
                "symfony/asset": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/console": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/dotenv": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/expression-language": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/form": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/http-client": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/lock": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/mailer": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/messenger": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/mime": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "~1.0",
                "symfony/process": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/property-info": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/security-csrf": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/security-http": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/serializer": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/stopwatch": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/string": "~5.0.0",
                "symfony/translation": "^5.0",
                "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/validator": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/web-link": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/workflow": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "symfony/yaml": "^4.4|^5.0",
                "twig/twig": "^2.10|^3.0"
            },
            "suggest": {
                "ext-apcu": "For best performance of the system caches",
                "symfony/console": "For using the console commands",
                "symfony/form": "For using forms",
                "symfony/property-info": "For using the property_info service",
                "symfony/serializer": "For using the serializer service",
                "symfony/validator": "For using validation",
                "symfony/web-link": "For using web links, features such as preloading, prefetching or prerendering",
                "symfony/yaml": "For using the debug:config and lint:yaml commands"
            },
            "type": "symfony-bundle",
            "extra": {
                "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "5.0-dev"
                }
            },
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\": ""
                },
                "exclude-from-classmap": [
                    "/Tests/"
                ]
            },
            "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
            "license": [
                "MIT"
            ],
            "authors": [
                {
                    "name": "Fabien Potencier",
                    "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Symfony Community",
                    "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Symfony FrameworkBundle",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
            "support": {
                "source": "https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/tree/v5.0.11"
            },
            "funding": [
                {
                    "url": "https://symfony.com/sponsor",
                    "type": "custom"
                },
                {
                    "url": "https://github.com/fabpot",
                    "type": "github"
                },
                {
                    "url": "https://tidelift.com/funding/github/packagist/symfony/symfony",
                    "type": "tidelift"
                }
            ],
            "time": "2020-07-23T08:36:09+00:00"
        },
    ...
}
```

**`symfony.lock`**

```
{
    ...
    "symfony/framework-bundle": {
        "version": "4.4",
        "recipe": {
            "repo": "github.com/symfony/recipes",
            "branch": "master",
            "version": "4.4",
            "ref": "23ecaccc551fe2f74baf613811ae529eb07762fa"
        },
        "files": [
            "config/bootstrap.php",
            "config/packages/cache.yaml",
            "config/packages/framework.yaml",
            "config/packages/test/framework.yaml",
            "config/routes/dev/framework.yaml",
            "config/services.yaml",
            "public/index.php",
            "src/Controller/.gitignore",
            "src/Kernel.php"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the vendor folder, `package.lock`, `symfony.lock` and installing again the dependencies?

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your `composer.json`. I would assume that any other dependency is listed there that blocks the update - `Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"` sounds like you are using Flex?

Comment: @Romainbiard I don't want to use such rough methods. In real world project dependencies should be updated one by one.

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated the question with the content of the `composer.json`, `composer.lock`, and `symfony.lock`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are already using multiple versions of Symfony packages in your `composer.json`, like:

```
    "symfony/asset": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/routing": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.0.*"
```

You should clean that up to avoid incompatible packages. Do this either by using Flex, or by setting all package versions by hand

---

**Usage of Flex**

Set all Symfony related dependencies to `"*"`, configure the Symfony version like this:

```
"extra": {
  "symfony": {
    "require": "5.2.*"
  }
},
```

Afterwards, update the Symfony dependencies through `composer update "symfony/*"`.

Any later upgrade to the next version requires only a single change in this section.

---

**"Manual" configuration**

Set all Symfony related dependencies to `"5.2.*"`, update them through `composer update "symfony/*"`

Comment: Hi Nico, thank you very much for your answer! The second solution didn't work. The reason is, that there are some packages, that there are some nested dependencies (meaning "dependencies of dependencies"), that are not not explicitly specified in the `composer.json`. But the first variant has worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Just one mor question: After the update the `composer.lock` has changed as expected: All `symfony/*` packages have the minor version `5.2`. But in the `symfony.lock` all packages (expect `symfony/string`) have the version `5.0`. Does the `symfony.lock` need to be updated separately? How to get it in sync with the `composer.lock` again?

Comment: If you want to update your recipes, `composer sync-recipes --force` can help, but that might also cause new issues

Answer (score 4):

Considering your output:

> Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"

You currently have something like this in your composer.json:

```json
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "require": "5.0.*"
    }
  },
```

Which means you can't update to Symfony packaged greater than `5.0.*`.

But now you are trying to install the framework-bundle on a greater version, but you can't update the individual components.

The way to do this "cleanly" is to do it step by step.

First change your required Symfony version to 5.2.*, update all Symfony packages to this version (which yes, will require you issuing a `composer update`), deal with any problems (if any) after the update, and **then** install the framework-bundle you were going to install.