# Try to update Sonata, have error with jms-serializer

Tags: symfony, project-management, sonata, jms-serializer, sonata-media-bundle

I need to update my bundles for security reasons but when i try to do a composer update, i have a lot of problem with sonata.

First, SonataCore, sonataMedia and JMS-serializer disappear.

[bundles.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxtu2.png)

If a tried to reinstall SonataCore with `composer require sonata-project/core-bundle`

i have this error: `Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires sonata-project/core-bundle ^3.20 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/core-bundle[3.20.0]. - sonata-project/core-bundle 3.20.0 requires sonata-project/form-extensions ^0.1 -> found sonata-project/form-extensions[0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2] but the package is fixed to 1.16.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.`

If a tried to reinstall SonataMedia with `composer require sonata-project/media-bundle`,

i have this error: `Problem 1 - sonata-project/media-bundle[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.5] require doctrine/persistence ^2.0 -> found doctrine/persistence[2.0.0, ..., 2.5.3] but the package is fixed to 1.3.8 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command. - Root composer.json requires sonata-project/media-bundle ^4.1 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/media-bundle[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.5].`

I can install JMS-Serializer but then, i have an error with `jms_serializer.handler_registry` even though i use it nowhere in my code (but it appears in the cache).

My `composer.json` :

```
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.5",
        "dekalee/mailjet-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/common": "^2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.6",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
        "hslavich/oneloginsaml-bundle": "^1.4",
        "jmose/command-scheduler-bundle": "^2.2",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^4.0",
        "michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle": "^4.0",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.5",
        "paragonie/halite": "^4",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.10",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.56",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.12",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^4.1",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.7",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.5",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.12"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.5",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "ocramius/package-versions": true,
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": "true",
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a novice in project management so i have no idea how to resolve all of this, i hope you can help me.

Comment: Please, post your composer.json. And avoid using screenshots, raw code is better for context reproduction

Comment: Maybe you should read this, it can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120565/how-to-resolve-the-composer-dependencies-conflicts-a-clean-way

Comment: I've added my composer.json.